# What is the maximum rate of change of $f(x,y,z) = x + \frac yz$ at the point $(5, -3, 5)$ and the direction in which it occurs.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

What is the maximum rate of change of  $f(x,y,z) = x + \frac yz$ at the point $(5, -3, 5)$ and the direction in which it occurs?

As an answer I got $1.02683981223947$ for the maximum rate of change. Being the magnitude of the gradient. However for the unit vector I got $\left \langle 1, \frac15, \frac3{25}\right \rangle$. I got that from $dx=1,\,dy=\frac1z,\,dz=-\frac y{z^2}$. The maximum rate of change I got was correct but the unit vector was incorrect (In all three parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$( 1,\frac15,\frac 3 {25}) $ isn't a unit vector; divide  by its magnitude  (the value you mentioned above )

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that still gives me the wrong answer. https://imgur.com/a/3BRHv <---- the question box

Comment: @C. Jones See my edit...

Answer (score 2):

The maximum rate of change occurs in the direction of the gradient of $f$ and has the magnitude of the gradient of $f$.
$$f\left( {x,y,z} \right) = x + \frac{y}{z}$$
$$\nabla f\left( {x,y,z} \right) = \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}\hat x + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}\hat y + \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial z}}\hat z$$
$$\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} = \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left( {x + \frac{y}{z}} \right) = 1 = {\rm{constant}}$$
$$\frac{{\partial f}}{{dy}} = \frac{\partial }{{\partial y}}\left( {x + \frac{y}{z}} \right) = \frac{1}{z}$$
$$\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial z}}\left( {x + \frac{y}{z}} \right) = y\frac{\partial }{{\partial z}}\left( {\frac{1}{z}} \right) =  - y{z^{ - 2}}$$

$$\boxed{\nabla f\left( {x,y,z} \right) = \underbrace {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}}_1\hat x + \underbrace {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}}_{\frac{1}{z}}\hat y + \underbrace {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial z}}\hat z}_{ - y{z^{ - 2}}} = \hat x + \frac{1}{z}\hat y - y{z^{ - 2}}}$$

The maximum rate of change is the magnitude of the gradient at $\left( {5, - 3,5} \right)$.
$$\boxed{\nabla f\left( {5, - 3,5} \right) = \hat x + \frac{1}{5}\hat y - \left( { - 3} \right){\left( 5 \right)^{ - 2}} = \hat x + \frac{1}{5}\hat y + \frac{3}{{25}}\hat z}$$

So at (5,3,5):
$$\left| {\nabla f\left( {5, - 3,5} \right)} \right| = \sqrt {1 + {5^{ - 2}} + {{\left( { - 3} \right)}^2}{{\left( 5 \right)}^{ - 4}}}  = \sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{{25}} + \frac{9}{{25 \cdot 25}}}  $$

$25^2 = 625$. So:
$$\left| {\nabla f\left( {5, - 3,5} \right)} \right| = \sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{{25}} + \frac{9}{{25 \cdot 25}}}  = \sqrt {\frac{{{{25}^2}}}{{{{25}^2}}} + \frac{{25}}{{{{25}^2}}} + \frac{9}{{{{25}^2}}}}  = \sqrt {\frac{{625 + 25 + 9}}{{{{25}^2}}}}  = \frac{1}{{25}}\sqrt {659}  \approx 1.0268$$
$$\boxed{\left| {\nabla f\left( {5, - 3,5} \right)} \right| = \frac{1}{{25}}\sqrt {659}  \approx 1.0268}$$

The direction of the maximum rate of increase it the direction of the gradient.
$$\frac{{\nabla f\left( {5, - 3,5} \right)}}{{\left| {\nabla f\left( {5, - 3,5} \right)} \right|}} = \frac{{\hat x + \frac{1}{5}\hat y + \frac{3}{{25}}\hat z}}{{\frac{1}{{25}}\sqrt {659} }} = \frac{{25}}{{\sqrt {659} }}\hat x + \frac{{25}}{{\sqrt {659} }}\frac{1}{5}\hat y + \frac{{25}}{{\sqrt {659} }}\frac{3}{{25}}\hat z$$

$$\frac{{\nabla f\left( {5, - 3,5} \right)}}{{\left| {\nabla f\left( {5, - 3,5} \right)} \right|}} = \frac{{25}}{{\sqrt {659} }}\hat x + \frac{5}{{\sqrt {659} }}\hat y + \frac{3}{{\sqrt {659} }}\hat z = \boxed{\frac{1}{{\sqrt {659} }}\left( {25\hat x + 5\hat y + 3\hat z} \right)}$$

$$\boxed{\frac{1}{{\sqrt {659} }}\left( {25,5,3} \right)}$$